# efficient way of getting unique values by comparing columns in two dataframes pandas

Tags: pandas, comparison, unique

I have two dataframes, something like below:

```
  df1:

   date             col1          col2         col3
 15-5-2022          ABC            1            PQR
 16-5-2022          BCD            2            ABC
 17-5-2022          CDE            4            XYZ


  df2:

   date           col1          col2         col3
 5-4-2022          XYZ            1           ABC
 6-4-2022          PQR            2           ABC
 7-4-2022          BCD            4           PQR
```

My task is to get total number of unique values that are in df2.col1 but not in df1.col1. The way I am doing this is by creating first a list of all col1 unique values from df1 and then from df2 and then comparing these two lists and creating a third list with what exists in second list but not the first. Since I need the count of items in the final list, I am doing a len on third list. My code is like below:

```
list1 = df1.col1.unique()    
list2 = df2.col1.unique()
list3 = [x for x in list2 if x not in list1]
num_list3 = len(list3)
```

This is getting my task done, but taking a very long time to run, probably because my dfs are quite big. I was wondering if there is a smarter and more efficient way of doing this please. I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df2.loc[~df2['col1'].isin(df1['col1']), 'col1'].unique()
```

output: `array(['XYZ', 'PQR'], dtype=object)`

Or, with sets:

```
set(df2['col1']) - set(df1['col1'])
```

output: `{'PQR', 'XYZ'}`

Comment: df2.loc[~df2['col1'].isin(df2['col1']), 'col1'].unique(), where is this comparing with df1.col1 please?

Comment: There was a typo, I fixed it

Comment: gives me nothing
Series([], Name: col1, dtype: int64)

Comment: Do you have a complete overlap? I just tested with the provided dataset and it works well. Please provide a reproducible example of a failing case

Comment: no, for sure not

Comment: Can you test with your example? Does it work?

Comment: I seem to have done something wrong when I tested it before. It works now, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I encounter a similar problem but more difficult. My problem is to compare the unique combination and get the differences between `df1` and `df2`. Here I post the 2 solutions in case you need them.

**Solution key idea:** Using a trick of `concat`, `groupby` or `merge`.

If you want to get the joint or the mutual of the two dataframes. By getting unique of `df1`, and `df2`, called `u1` and `u2`. You concat `u1`, and `u2`, then use `groupby` to count for the number of occurance. If more than 1 then it appears in both `u1` and `u2`. If it is 1, then it appears in one of the two `u1` or `u2`.

If you want to get the uniques from `df1` or `df2` only, then use `merge` trick with option `indicator=True`

**Data set for replication:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':['a','a','b','b','c','d','e'],
                   'val': [1,2,1,3,4,5,6]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id':['a','a','b','b','c','c','e','f','f','d'],
                   'val': [1,2,1,3,4,5,5,7,8,9]})
```

**Problem 1:** a single column comparison

```
# Getting unique in each dataframe and concat
u1 = pd.DataFrame(df1['id'].unique(), columns=['id'])
u2 = pd.DataFrame(df2['id'].unique(), columns=['id'])
u = pd.concat([u1,u2])

# Groupby, count the number of occurrence with function `size`:
u.groupby('id').size().reset_index()

# You can do the rest by your choice if you want the joint or the not joint part
```

**Problem 2:** multiple columns combination

```
# Getting unique combination of `id` and `val` by using trick of `size()` in `groupby`:

u1 = df1.groupby(['id', 'val']).size().reset_index().drop(columns=0)
u2 = df2.groupby(['id', 'val']).size().reset_index().drop(columns=0)
u = pd.concat([u1,u2])

# Groupby, count the number of occurrence with function `size`:
u.groupby('id').size().reset_index()

# You can do the rest by your choice if you want the joint or the not joint part
```

**If you need uique of `df1` or `df2` only**

```
# This will tell you the uniques combinations belong to df1 or df2 or both:    
pd.merge(u1, u2, how='outer', on='id', indicator=True)
```

This should speed up your old code.

Hope this help